# pry on rspec in cloud 9 ide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cloud9-ide

I am new to RoR. I have two problems here.
**ISSUE 1**
my rspec is

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe RefUserCategory do
    describe "validations" do
        it { should validate_presence_of(:user_category_description) }
    end
end
```

my Ref_User_Category model is

```
class RefUserCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :user_category_description , presence: true
    has_many :Users
end
```

The error I got in Rspec is 
`Expected errors to include /can't be blank/ when user_category_description is set to nil, got no errors`

So I decided to to use Pry to check whats happening

**ISSUE 2**
Im my application folder I do

```
pry -r ./config/environment

[2] pry(main)> Ref_User_Category.new
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Ref_User_Category, expected /var/lib/stickshift/52d29d0e5004461024000031/app-root/data/736003/east/app/models/ref_user_category.rb to define it
from /var/lib/stickshift/52d29d0e5004461024000031/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:464:in `load_missing_constant'
```

I have user model too I

```
pry(main)> User.new
```

gives error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'

/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:512:in `table_structure'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding **issue 1**, you have a typo: change `validate` to `validates`.

Regarding **issue 2**:

You generally start the console from the *root* of your project like this:

```
$ rails c
```

You are doing `Ref_User_Category.new` when you should do `RefUserCategory.new`.

About `User.new`, it looks like you haven't run your database migrations:

```
$ rake db:migrate
$ rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: I have done rake db:migrate. Or else Rspec execution would have suggested me the same . In any case I tried again `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` still not working

Comment: What does `$ rake db:test:prepare` outputs? Also, do you run `rails console` from the root folder of your project?

Comment: rake db:test:prepare give no output. Thanks for the pointer it was issue with rails console no executed properly was getting error `config.eager_load is set to nil` got it fixed thanks :) working now

Comment: @Rigel also added solution for issue 1 and more solutions for 2.